# My Node.js azure function is returning huge data. How to compress the json response?

Tags: node.js, json, compression, azure-functions

I have a Node.js azure function. It returns a big JSON file, which is taking close to a minute to return to UI. How to compress it so that the performance of the application improves?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [`zlib`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html) core module to compress the data before sending it out. Make sure to set the `Content-Encoding` header value to `gzip` so that clients to decompress data accordingly.

Something like this should do

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const gzip = promisify(zlib.gzip);

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

  var res = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
  };

  if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
    // res.status = 200; /* Defaults to 200 */
    res.body = await gzip("Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name));
  }
  else {
    res.status = 400;
    res.body = await gzip("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
  }

  context.res = res;
}
```

Comment: Good use of Promisify:
The promisify function enables you to write asynchronous, non-blocking code using Promises, which aligns with Node.js's event-driven, single-threaded architecture. This, in turn, allows for efficient handling of concurrent operations and prevents the main thread from being blocked, resulting in better performance and responsiveness.